# Serial Hangs with multiple PN532 nfc reader and a TCA9548A

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, multiplexer, nfc

I am trying to use multiple PN532 reader. I have put all my readers on a multiplexer (TCA9548A).

The script works well, but when I move my tags on readers sometimes the serial says to me there is an error on reading tag like that : `Read failed [number]` or like `Error. Failed read page [number]` where [number] is a Integer.

And sometimes the serial completely hangs and not sends anything anymore, I have to reset the arduino by pressing the reset button.

### Other information :

Arduino : My arduino is a Mega.

Here is my code :

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <PN532_I2C.h>
#include <PN532.h>
#include <NfcAdapter.h>

#define TCAADDR 0x70

#define RST_PIN 2

PN532_I2C pn532_i2c(Wire);
NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter(pn532_i2c);

int NB_NFC_READER = 4;

void tcaselect(uint8_t i) 
{
  if (i > 7) return;
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCAADDR);
  Wire.write(1 << i);
  Wire.endTransmission();  
}

void setup(void) 
{
    while (!Serial);
    delay(250);

    Wire.begin();

    // Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.begin(9600);

    //Serial.println("NDEF Reader");


    /**Initialisation des lecteurs NFC*/
    for(int i = 0 ; i < NB_NFC_READER ; i++)
    {
      //Serial.println("CONFIGURATION DU READER N° " + String(i));
      tcaselect(i);
      nfc.begin();  
    }

    pinMode(RST_PIN, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(RST_PIN, HIGH);

    Serial.println("SETUP OK !");
}

void loop(void) 
{  
  String tag0;
  String tag1;
  String tag2;
  String tag3;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < NB_NFC_READER ; i++)
    { 
      //Serial.println("FOR INDEX : " + String(i));
      tcaselect(i);
      if (nfc.tagPresent(100))
      {
          NfcTag tag = nfc.read();
          //tag.print();
          if(i == 0)
          {
            tag0 = tag.getUidString();
          }
          if(i == 1)
          {
            tag1 = tag.getUidString();
          }
          if(i == 2)
          {
            tag2 = tag.getUidString();
          }
          if(i == 3)
          {
            tag3 = tag.getUidString();
          }
          //Serial.println("LECTURE SUR LECTEUR " + tag.getUidString());
          delay(100);
      }
    }
    Serial.print("[");
    Serial.print("{\"tag0\":");Serial.print("\"");Serial.print(tag0);Serial.print("\"},");
    Serial.print("{\"tag1\":");Serial.print("\"");Serial.print(tag1);Serial.print("\"},");
    Serial.print("{\"tag2\":");Serial.print("\"");Serial.print(tag2);Serial.print("\"},");
    Serial.print("{\"tag3\":");Serial.print("\"");Serial.print(tag3);Serial.print("\"}");
    Serial.println("]");
}
```

Thank you for reading, I hope someone will find why the serial freeze like that.

Comment: Set debiggung to verbose in the IDE, maybe this reveals some more info. It's unlikely that the actual serial output of the atmega freezes. I guess, either the sketch hangs somewhere else or it is the software on the frontend failing